# Creating a selection function that selects images on a pre-made page and pops an alert when you click on them

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to go to this page:

http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/dyson.html

Add a script that will select only the product images on the tiles and when I click on them will create an alert with potentially their price on it but right now I'd be happy with just a random phrase.

I am going to assume that I need to loop into an array just those images and maybe use an addeventlistener for those images that I just tagged?  Is there any way to do this without going into each image and adding an ID to it.

Comment: Please do not deface posts. They belong to the community once posted.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fetch all product elements, I chose this selector `.product-tile-srp__content-wrapper`
Then, for each product, attach a `click` event and then fetch the price from `.product-tile__price`

Here's the code:

```
var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product-tile-srp__content-wrapper');

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var product = this;
    var price = product.querySelector('.product-tile__price').innerText;
    window.alert(price);
  });
}
```

Note that the for loop is important because the `NodeList.forEach` is not supported on IE.

Comment: Thank you so much, may I ask how did you so easily find .product-tile-srp__content-wrapper and .product-tile__price ?

Comment: I used the DevTools in my browser. Every browser has its own DevTools 

Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/son/docs/Tools

And then I inspect the elements starting by the price itself, going up in the DOM tree till I find the product wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery this is pretty simple, just select based on the class. You need to also prevent the click from causing the browser to navigate to the product page. Then you can get the price by searching the descendants for the element containing the price. In my example, since I just selected the image and not the whole product element, I first had to search up through the ancestors (with `closest`) to get the base product element, and then find the price element.

Here is the example which activates when you click the image, just enter this into your browser's console while on the page:

```
$('.product-tile-srp__image').on('click', (e) => {
    // Prevent click from actually opening the product page
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    price = $(e.target).closest('.product-tile-srp__content-wrapper').find('.product-tile__price').text();
    alert(price);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, may I ask how did you so easily find .product-tile-srp__content-wrapper and .product-tile__price ?